# Finding speed/magnitude of r prime

Tags: calculus, vectors

I need to find the speed of a particle with $r(t) = \langle \sqrt{2}t i, e^t j, e^{-t} k \rangle$

I have $r' = \langle\sqrt{2}i, e^tj, -e^{-t}k\rangle$

and got $\|r'(t)\|= \sqrt{ 2 + e^{2t}+e^{-2t}}$

But the answer is listed as just $\|r'(t)\| = e^t+e^{-t}$

How are they getting this?

Comment: 1. Use \langle and \rangle for the braces, \sqrt{} for a square root. 2. If $r$ is a vector, it doesn't make sense to be summing the components inside the braces as you have written. 3. Your $\| r' \|$ is wrong, it should be $\sqrt{2 + e^{2t} + e^{-2t}}$.

Comment: Ok, fixed, thanks.

Comment: And from your solution

\begin{align}
\sqrt{2 + e^{2t} + e^{-2t}} &= \sqrt{2 + 2 \cosh(2t)} \\
&= \sqrt{2(1 + \cosh(2t))} \\
&= \sqrt{2 \cdot 2 \cosh^{2}(t)} \\
&= 2 \cosh(t) \\
&= 2 \cdot \frac{e^{t} + e^{-t}}{2} \\
&= e^{t} + e^{-t}
\end{align}

Comment: Ok.. the teachers need to communicate whats in each class better. Non of the earlier classes ever mentioned anything about cosh and now I'm getting HW that involves it...  Thank you for the answer, glad to have this site and the people on it.

Comment: Don't be dazed by the $\cosh$. That's just how Mattos found it most comfortable to think of it. Myself, whenever I see two powers plus twice something halfway between them - $x^2+2xy+y^2$ or $x^2+2+x^{-2}$ or even $x+2+x^{-1}$ - I think "this must be a square!" And I go on from there.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2+e^{2t}+e^{-2t}=(e^t)^2+2e^te^{-t}+(e^{-t})^2=(e^t+e^{-t})^2$